# Can't place rays from some start to some end

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, raycasting

I have a start and end, i need to place an adjustable amount of rays on the line from start to end. But I can't figure out how to correctle place them. I almost finished, but rays is not placed at the end.

*Green (2, 0, 2)* for start and *Red (2, 0, -2)* for end with *distance between 4*

[image]

This is my result with 2 rays, the center ray need to be at the end (red ray), and next rays add should be at the center of start and end rays

[image]

What happens if i adding third ray, the end ray position isn't in use

[image]

And 5 rays. The first and the last rays need to be at the start and the end. Other 3 rays should to be between

[image]

This is my code:

```
public class VehicleAroundCast : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int sideRaysAmount;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 offset;

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 startRayPos = transform.position + Vector3.left * offset.x + Vector3.forward * offset.z;
        Vector3 endRayPos = transform.position + Vector3.left * offset.x + Vector3.back * offset.z;
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(startRayPos, endRayPos);

        Debug.DrawRay(startRayPos, Vector3.down, Color.green);
        Debug.DrawRay(endRayPos, Vector3.down, Color.red);

        for (int i = 0; i < sideRaysAmount; i++)
        {
            float step = dist / sideRaysAmount * i;
            Vector3 position = (transform.position + Vector3.left * offset.x + Vector3.forward * offset.z) + Vector3.back * step;

            Debug.DrawRay(position, Vector3.down);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you concidered using Debug.DrawLine ?

Comment: @zambari so difference? I am using Debug.DrawRay

Comment: well, I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but with Line you specify start and end point, instead of start point and direction

Comment: @zambari i need a line of raycasts looking down placing them from start to end. Start - first raycast, end - last raycast and between other raycasts if the will be

Comment: You say the end ray is not placed apparently, in the images the end ray (red) is visible though. Did you mean that the start ray is not placed?

Comment: @CBX_MG, green and red are abstract rays, white is real rays, i need them placed along a line from start to end include start and end. It means that for 2 rays i need them at green and red, for 3 rays i need 2 on green and red, and 1 between them. If raysAmount is 1, first white ray placing at green ray, if raysAmount is 2, white rays placing first at green ray and last at red ray, if raysAmount is bigger than 2, white rays need to be placed first at green ray, and next rays need to be placed at center but the last ray need to be placed at red ray. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up from the clarification through the comment I'd do a couple of things a bit different. I'll just edit your code so that it should work as you'd need it to and explain it in code comments.

```
public class VehicleAroundCast : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] [Min(0)] private int intermediateRayCount;
    // I renamed this field so the name is more descriptive, intermediate meaning between start and end
    // to make sure that no number below 0 can be assigned I added the [Min(0)] attribute, a number
    // below 0 would break the logic and wouldn't make sense

    [SerializeField] private Vector3 offset;

    private void Update ()
    {
        // we don't want to clog up our Update() method with tons of lines of code
        // this serves better maintainability as well
        CastRays();
    }

    private void CastRays ()
    {
        Vector3 startRayPos = transform.position + Vector3.left * offset.x + Vector3.forward * offset.z;
        Vector3 endRayPos = transform.position + Vector3.left * offset.x + Vector3.back * offset.z;

        // if we don't have any intermediate rays we can save on the calculation that is necessary when we
        // have intermediates, we just cast the the two rays and end the method by returning
        if (intermediateRayCount == 0)
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(startRayPos, Vector3.down, Color.green);
            Debug.DrawRay(endRayPos, Vector3.down, Color.red);

            return;
        }

        // instead of using Vector3.Distance() we'll calculate the directional vector manually this way
        // we can get not only the distance (directional vectors magnitude) but the direction to move
        // along to space the rays as well

        // subtarting the start position from the end position gives us the directional vector
        Vector3 direction = endRayPos - startRayPos;
        // a directional vectors magnitude gives the distance from start to end
        float distance = direction.magnitude;
        // after the distance has been established we normalize the direction so that it's length is 1
        direction.Normalize();

        // we have at least two rays (start and end) so our total is the rays between start and end plus two
        int totalRayCount = intermediateRayCount + 2;
        // the space between the individual rays, we have to subtract one from the totalRayCount in order to 
        // place the the last ray at the end position (yes this could be optimized but I want to write out 
        // the logic fully so that it's clear what happens)
        float spacing = distance / (totalRayCount - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < totalRayCount; i++)
        {
            // we can simply get the ray position by adding the direction multiplied by the spacing multiplied
            // by the number of iterations we've gone through to the start position
            // since the direction is normalized we can multiply it by the distance between rays to give it
            // the length between two rays, if we then multiply it by the number of rays the current ray is,
            // we get the distance as well as direction the current ray has to be placed away from the start
            // position
            Vector3 rayPosition = startRayPos + direction * spacing * i;

            // i added some color so you can see start and end
            if (i == 0) 
                Debug.DrawRay(startRayPos, Vector3.down, Color.green);
            else if (i == totalRayCount - 1) 
                Debug.DrawRay(endRayPos, Vector3.down, Color.red);
            else 
                Debug.DrawRay(rayPosition, Vector3.down, Color.white);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the complex solve of the problem. The code I've attached was just a sketch of code. I just wanted try to write the solution that solves my problem. As i can see, you wrote the code where intermediateRayCount is controls only the rays between the start and the end. And the start and the end rays are always be casted. Am i understood it correctly?

Comment: Correct. I didn't see a need for an implementation of code for the situation of only one ray. Intermediate means "between two points", in this case between start and end. For code efficiency I separated out the situation of no intermediate rays, as described. If you'd want support for just one ray in the same method you could do a similar thing, I'd advise against it though.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple logic mistake.

You wanted `sideRaysAmount` to be the amount of **rays**. But you are using it as amount of **steps** in between rays.

There is always exactly one step less than rays.

=> For the calculation of `step` you simply want to use

```
float step = dist / (sideRaysAmount - 1) * i;
```

so e.g.

```
var startRayPos = transform.position + Vector3.left * offset.x + Vector3.forward * offset.z;
var endRayPos = transform.position + Vector3.left * offset.x + Vector3.back * offset.z;  

var dist = Vector3.Distance(startRayPos, endRayPos);

var stepSize = sideRaysAmount == 1 ? 0 : dist / (sideRaysAmount - 1f);

Debug.DrawRay(startRayPos, Vector3.down, Color.green);
Debug.DrawRay(endRayPos, Vector3.down, Color.red);

for (var i = 0; i < sideRaysAmount; i++)
{
    var step = i * stepSize;
    var position = transform.position + Vector3.left * offset.x + Vector3.forward * offset.z + Vector3.back * step;

    Debug.DrawRay(position, Vector3.down);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try it later on project, then give feedback.

Comment: You code is also working correctly. Thanks!